# Why is my control scheme is not casual enough?

Tags: 2d, game-design, control

I am building a game like counter strike but 2dimensional and for android, it is already in beta phase. I have already share it with my friends and classmates to play it. Almost all of them said the controls are bad. Followings are the current controls:

> tap on player: shoot
>
> tap NOT on player: pathfind to touchposition
>
> vertical drag on screen: rotate the camera left or right

The camera position and rotation will respect the player's position and rotation to help them aim before shooting. I am trying to build this game as casual as possible, so the player can only shoot, hide (stop moving/idle), and seek (move). Is there a better controls or gameplay than the current one? I am willing to cut features or change the whole gameplay.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a beta test, so did you ask them why they thought the controls were bad? Did you ask them for suggestions? this information would help us.

Comment: If the camera snaps directly to position+rotation, then it will be difficult to click precisely while pathfinding. Can you give us more detail about how your camera works?

Comment: I think what this question is actually about is how to extract useful feedback from playtesters. "X is bad" isn't really useful feedback. The question is *why* are the controls perceived as bad. Do they try to do thing X but do thing Y instead? Or do they want to do X but can't because it is too cumbersome and frustrating to do?

Comment: Two things: When you say *vertical* drag (up / down) did you mean *horizontal* (left / right)? And when the player taps to shoot do they shoot straight ahead (as in; do you have to rotate the camera to the right to shoot to the right)?

Comment: I think it has to do with your presentation; your explanation is that it is like counter strike but in 2d from that it's expected that it's a skill based direct control game where your aim is to shoot the enemy, but your control scheme is closer to a RTS game where you control a single unit instead. If you think you're getting 2d csgo but it controls like SC2 then players assume it's bad design rather than intended